# how to don`t send a specific column (computed columns) from class to Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am using a class table named `Circulation` in SQL Server 2012, and I have the same table in C#.

`Circulation` table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Circulation]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Document_Id] [int] NULL,
    [Person_Id] [int] NULL,
    [Librarian_Id] [int] NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [EndDate]  AS ([StartDate]+[Time]),
    [Time] [int] NULL,
    [Delay] [int] NULL,
    [IsReturned] [bit] NULL
)
```

and C# `Circulation` class:

```
 public Circulation() : base()
 {
 }

 public Circulation(int document_Id, int person_Id, int librarian_Id, DateTime startDate, double time, string delay, bool isReturned) : base()
 {
        Document_Id = document_Id;
        Person_Id = person_Id;
        Librarian_Id = librarian_Id;
        StartDate = startDate;
        Time = time;
        Delay = delay;
        IsReturned = isReturned;
}

public int Document_Id { get; set; }
public int Person_Id { get; set; }
public int Librarian_Id { get; set; }
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
public double Time { get; set; }
public string Delay { get; set; }
public bool IsReturned { get; set; }
```

Because I am using this code to run save procedure :

```
public virtual int Save()
{
        var command = new SqlCommand("Save_" + this.GetType().Name, Db.GetSqlConnection());

        try
        {
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            foreach (var item in this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(item => item.Name != "Message"))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(item.Name, item.GetValue(this, null));
            }

            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

            var ds = new DataSet();

            adapter.Fill(ds);

           // this.Message = ds.Tables[1].Rows[0][0].ToString();

            return int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            return -1;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (command.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                command.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

According to the code, if I add the "End Date" property to the c# `Circulation` object, the procedure will be unable to run because the "End date" is a computed column and if I do not add this property to the c# table, I will be unable to get this data from the database.

How can I add this property to the c# class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of Attributes seems the way to go.

Create a class `IgnoreAttribute`

```
class IgnoreAttribute : Attribute
{ }
```

Add the property to your c# class, decorated with the attribute

```
class Circulation
{
    [Ignore]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

And in your Save method, check for the attribute

```
foreach (var item in this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(item => item.Name != "Message"))
{
    if (!item.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<IgnoreAttribute>().Any())
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(item.Name, item.GetValue(this, null));
    }
}
```

Comment: which attribute ? Thanks